# Getting Permission denied error while installing grafana in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, grafana

I am trying to install grafana in docker container but getting permission denied error. Below are the details :

```
sudo docker build -t grafana:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.12 kB
Step 1/8 : FROM grafana/grafana:6.3.5
 ---> 2017e1eb54fa
Step 2/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gettext-base && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 4c3b0835bb22

Reading package lists...
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gettext-base && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I have tried running it using sudo but that didn't work. Also I have tried

```
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gettext-base && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

but this also didn't work.

Below is the dockerfile

```
FROM grafana/grafana:6.3.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gettext-base && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /etc/grafana
COPY datasources ./datasources

WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod u+x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:6.3.5
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gettext-base && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER grafana
WORKDIR /etc/grafana
COPY datasources ./datasources

WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.sh ./

RUN chmod u+x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

the image use the default user: `grafana`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `docker commit` to make your changes permanent. it's easier than build a new image with `dockerfile`.

first you should go inside container, then make your changes like upgrading or changing configs and finally commit changes.

```
host$ docker exec -it "container_name/id" bash
container# apt-get update
host$ docker commit "container_name/id" my-grafana
```

You can see image list with `docker image ls`